# Sql how to select from a table that does not exist in another table

Tags: php, mysql

For example i have 2 tables that have relationship with one another. **room_directory.id** and **booked_room.room_id**

### room_directory

```
id
room_number
```

### booked_room

```
id
booking_id
room_id
```

How to write query that select only the rooms from **room_directory** that are not exists in **booked_room** table?

Comment: Could you try looking up the MySQL `NOT EXISTS` expression and let us know if you have trouble implementing it.

Comment: Select * from room_directory where id not in(select room_id from booked_room)

Comment: Not exists is apparently more efficient ... check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists

Comment: What is the different between not exists and not in?

Comment: @Rafal That's for SQL Server, not applicable to MySQL.

Comment: @Khean `NOT IN` generates a list, then checks rows against the list, `NOT EXISTS` generates a pre-condition, then evaluates against that(which is likely to just be a list, and evaluated the same as `NOT IN`, but with a good index it could be far faster if MySQL just does a reverse match).

Comment: Thank you seems that NOT EXISTS is the most recommended I'll choose it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select * from room_directory r where r.id not in (select room_id from booked_room b where r.id = b.room_id);`

or

`SELECT * FROM room_directory r WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from booked_room b WHERE r.id = b.room_id);`

Comment: Do you mean NOT EXISTS?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from room_directory where id not in (select room_id from  booked_room)
```